# JQuery get data.source from REST and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to build a HTML page that will show an image inside a div, I need to read the source of the image via a REST service.
The REST response is a JSON object looks

```
{
   "photos": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "111111111",
            "source": "http://bla_blabla.com/bla1.jpg",
            "created_time": "2014-03-13T19:36:09+0000"
         },
         {
            "id": "22222222",
            "source": "http://bla_blabla.com/bla2.jpg",
            "created_time": "2014-03-13T07:55:04+0000"
        }
      ],},
   "created_time": "2010-07-24T18:23:25+0000",
   "id": "10150212006985032"
}
```

I used the following HTML code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="daily_cartoon">
</div>
```

And this was my JQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
url: "https://www.mysite.com/photos=photos.fields(id,source)"
}).then(function(data) {
$('#my_img_div').prepend('<img id="daily_img" src="' + data.source + '" />');
});
});
```

When I run my page, I got "undefiend" for the data.source!
I can see the data of the JSON object in the browser if i link to the service url directly (via browser's address bar) but not from the JQuery script.
If I tries to access data.id or data.created_time (from the footer section of the service), The values will return normally

Anyone can help me to find the missing part that makes me can't read the values of photos.data.source??

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It looks like data is an array of objects.  Try using data[0].source or data[1].source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look tells me that data is an array. so maybe something like `data[i].source`.

(or is is something like this: `data.photos.data[i]`)

Comment: Thank you verymuch data.photos.data[i] was the answer, I don't know how didn't try it :D

Answer (score 2):

The object returned is under the key of photos so we need to address that,and  then the `data` inside the `photos` object is an array so we need to iterate over it using a loop.

The code will be something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
url: "https://www.mysite.com/photos=photos.fields"
}).done(function(returnedData) {



   for(var i in returnedData.photos.data){
      $('#my_img_div').prepend('<img id="daily_img" src="' + returnedData.photos.data[i].source + '" />');
     }
});
});
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BT3DQ/) link.Open the javascript console and then run the script to see the output.

Comment: please also note in the code you posted URL is incorrect so can correct it , and you are most welcomed. :)

Comment: Thanks again shiva, actually I can't correct it because of security issues :)

Comment: If that is the correct format. Then add the missing quote in the `url` field of the ajax function.

Comment: you were right, i fixed the string, Thank you again